# Returning a string array from C# to Inno Setup

Tags: c#, inno-setup, dllexport, pascalscript

I'm using [Unmanaged Exports NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/UnmanagedExports) from Robert Giesecke and have the following method in C#:

```
[DllExport("DummyMethod", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static void DummyMethod(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 1)] out string[] test, out int count)
{
    count = 3;
    test = new[] {"test1", "test2", "test3"};
}
```

In Inno Setup this is my code:

```pascal
[Code]
procedure DummyMethod(out Test: TArrayOfString; out Count: Integer);
external 'DummyMethod@files:MyDll.dll stdcall';

procedure InitializeWizard();
  var Test : TArrayOfString;
  var Count : Integer;
begin
  DummyMethod(Test, Count);
  MsgBox(Test[0], mbError, MB_OK);
end;
```

For some reason, `Count` is always 0 and `Test` is always empty.

I have taken a look at several examples but couldn't find one where Inno Setup fetches a string array from a C# DLL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `UnmanagedType.LPArray` with `string` maps to an array of pointers to char (C-style `char**`). In Unicode Pascal Script that's `array of PAnsiChar`. There's no way the Pascal Script can magically convert that to `TArrayOfString` (`array of string`).

You can convert it like this:

```pascal
type
  TArrayOfPAnsiChar = array of PAnsiChar;

procedure DummyMethod(out StringPtrs: TArrayOfPAnsiChar; out Count: Integer);
  external 'DummyMethod@files:ArrayInno.dll stdcall';

function DummyMethodWrapper: TArrayOfString;
var
  ArrayOfPAnsiChar: TArrayOfPAnsiChar;
  I, Count: Integer;
begin
  DummyMethod(ArrayOfPAnsiChar, Count);

  SetArrayLength(Result, Count);
  for I := 0 to Count - 1 do
  begin
    Result[I] := ArrayOfPAnsiChar[I];
  end;
end;
```

*(Tested with Unicode Inno Setup)*

---

Side notes:

- It's not clear, who does a memory allocation for the `TArrayOfAnsiChar` and individual character arrays. I smell a memory leak, at best.
- You probably want to use 16-bit character buffer, not 8-bit character buffer to allow full Unicode. Though note that this is more difficult to implement in the Pascal Script as it lacks 16-bit character pointer type.

Comment: Your answer was of great help and the provided code works perfectly. The conversion from string[] to char** makes sense indeed. I haven't had much experience with these kind of setups and my knowledge beyond managed code is pretty confined. I did have to switch from non-unicode to unicode Inno Setup but I consider that a good thing! :)

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to marshal an array of `BSTR`/`WideString`, which should allow full Unicode.

In C#:

```
[DllExport("ReturnsArrayOfStrings", CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static void ReturnsArrayOfStrings(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.BStr, SizeParamIndex = 1)] out string[] values,
    out int numValues)
{
    values = new[] { "one", "two", "three" };
    numValues = values.Length;
}
```

In Inno Setup:

```pascal
type
  TArrayOfWideString = array of WideString;

procedure ReturnsArrayOfStrings(out values: TArrayOfWideString; out numValues: Integer);
external 'ReturnsArrayOfStrings@files:Thing.dll stdcall';

procedure DoAThing;
var
  values: TArrayOfWideString;
  numValues, i: Integer;
begin
  ReturnsArrayOfStrings(values, numValues);
  for i := 0 to numValues - 1 do
  begin
    Log(values[i]);
  end;  
end;
```